# Outlook JavaScript api attachments

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365

Currently developping an Office Add-In in JavaScript, I notice some differences in the API usability between the Outlook Windows rich client and the Office365 Web portal.

My add-in currently works like a charm in the "web" mode but not as expected in the Rich Client.

The add-in fetches the email body + attachments and sends it to a remote app server.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, { asyncContext: "html" }, function callback(resHtml) {

    // dealing with email in HTML format

});
```

For attachments, i'm doing it like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.length; i++) {
    var _att = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[i];

    attachments.assets.push({
        name: _att.name,
        id: _att.id,
        contentType: _att.contentType,
        size: _att.size,
        attachmentType: _att.attachmentType,
        isInline: _att.isInline
    });

}
```

(The JS add-in only sends attachment meta-data to the remote app. The remote app has to connect to Exchange EWS to actually fetch the attachments with the provided meta-data)

**The issue**

When there are inlined images attached in the email, the Web portal and the Rich client shows it completely differently in the output HTML :

**Web portal**

```
<img originalSrc="cid:image004.png@01D18392.E4A15FE0"   src="data:image/gif;base64,..." width="310" height="15" id="x__x0000_i1030" alt="...">
```

**Rich Client**

```
<img src="~WRS%7b0E0FFAA4-6FC0-49C1-9BB6-3D1A2F5211F1%7d_fichiers/image001.jpg" width=906 height=245 id="Picture 6">
```

On the other hand, the method `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments` returns this kind of objects :

```
{
    "_data$p$0": {
        "id": "AAMkAGI2MjY4MGQ....",
        "name": "image004.png",
        "contentType": "image/png",
        "size": 427,
        "attachmentType": 0,
        "isInline": true
    }
}
```

As it is pretty clear to map inlined images by their names to their "cid:XYZ" in the HTML for the Web Portal, how am I supposed to map them in the Rich Client ?

Little observation : even the `attachment` JS object says the image is something like `image003.png`, the `<img>` tag for the image doesn't reflet it at all and shows something like `~WRS...../image001.gif`. (filename not identicals, extensions mismatch)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, I post it here in case someone faces the same issue.

With the JS API, one can retrieve the access token that can be furtherly used back-end side to connect to SOAP Exchange Web Services (EWS).

The access token is retrievable via the `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` method

Once the token, the itemId and the EwsURL are gathered and sent to the back-end, you can use EWS to retrieve the mail body either in plain text or full HTML with inlined images correctly specified in the HTML.

You'll receive something like `<img src="cid:xyz@123" />` which is perfectly matchable with the attachment object previously retrieved.

Bonus: when connecting to EWS, you traditionally connect with a login/password couple. In this case, you don't know these credentials. 
the HTTP headers usually contains :

```
Authorization: Basic [credentials]
```

For authenticating to EWS via an access token, you have to set it as follow :

```
Authorization: Bearer [accessToken]
```